# What does "closed under subsets" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I understand what it means for a set to be closed under an operation, like addition or multiplication. But what does it mean for a set $T$ to be closed under subsets? Is subset an operation? I thought subsets were just sets with a certain property...

Comment: If $T$ is a collection of sets, $T$ is closed under subsets (or closed under taking subsets) if it has the following property: if $s\subseteq t\in T$, then $s\in T$. That is, every subset of a member of $T$ is also a member of $T$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thank you! That was very clear

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, you may want to write that up as an answer so this no longer remains as "unanswered".

Comment: @MarkS.: Done! $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is a collection of sets, $T$ is closed under subsets (or closed under taking subsets) if it has the following property: if $s\subseteq t\in T$, then $s\in T$. That is, every subset of a member of $T$ is also a member of $T$.